# how to create a vertical marquee in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have created a label within a panel and want to move it vertically .
    moving horizontally works using:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Start()

    If lbl1.Location.X + lbl1.Width < 0 Then
        lbl1.Location = New Point(Panel5.Width, lbl1.Location.Y)
    Else
        lbl1.Location = New Point(lbl1.Location.X - 4, lbl1.Location.Y)
    End If

End Sub
```

as u see in the above code (X) and (Y) is used for left and right drawing point. what is the drawing point for top and bottom

Comment: Are you saying you want the label to be rotated 90/-90 degrees or so the characters stack on top of each other?

Comment: If you want to stack vertically then use  height instead of width as your  offset.  only the Y will change for each label control.

Comment: thats the point . how to use height ? @SqlSurfer

Comment: The label control only uses the single point to place its location.  The Point class implies both X and Y so the Y is a function of the previous controls start point, height and a possible buffer space.

Comment: can u plz write the code @SqlSurfer

Answer (score 0):

Your **Horizontal** routine:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If lbl1.Location.X + lbl1.Width < 0 Then
        lbl1.Location = New Point(Panel5.Width, lbl1.Location.Y)
    Else
        lbl1.Location = New Point(lbl1.Location.X - 4, lbl1.Location.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Converted to a **Vertical** routine:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If lbl1.Location.Y + lbl1.Height < 0 Then
        lbl1.Location = New Point(lbl1.Location.X, Panel5.Height)
    Else
        lbl1.Location = New Point(lbl1.Location.X, lbl1.Location.Y - 4)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

take your idea n modify for my own requirement:

```
Private isFirstTime As Boolean = True

Public Sub RunningText(ByVal lbl As Label, ByVal pnl As Panel, Optional fromRightBottom As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal isHorizontal As Boolean = True)
    If isFirstTime Then
        If isHorizontal Then
            If fromRightBottom Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(pnl.Width, lbl.Location.Y)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(-1 * lbl.Width, lbl.Location.Y)
            End If
        Else
            If fromRightBottom Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, pnl.Height)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, 0)
            End If
        End If
        isFirstTime = False
    End If
    If isHorizontal Then
        If fromRightBottom Then
            If lbl.Location.X + lbl.Width < 0 Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(pnl.Width, lbl.Location.Y)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X - 4, lbl.Location.Y)
            End If
        Else
            If lbl.Location.X + pnl.Width > lbl.Width + pnl.Width Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(-1 * lbl.Width, lbl.Location.Y)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X + 4, lbl.Location.Y)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If fromRightBottom Then
            If lbl.Location.Y + lbl.Height < 0 Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, pnl.Height)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, lbl.Location.Y - 4)
            End If
        Else
            If lbl.Location.Y + lbl.Height > lbl.Height + pnl.Height Then
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, 0)
            Else
                lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, lbl.Location.Y + 4)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```